# Access/SQL update with duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question about how to write a query in Access when there are duplicated records in the table.

Say if I have the following two tables, `table1` is the table I would like to update by matching `field1` to `field1` in `table2`, and update the associated `field2` value. However, when there are more than one matching records in `table2`, I would like to update based on alphabetical order of the value.

Could you please show me how to do that? SQL code will be much appreciated.

**Table1**

```
Field1     |Field2
------------------
Male name  |?
Female name|?
```

**Table2**

```
Field1     |Field2
--------------------
Male name  | Alex
Male name  | Ben
Female name| Diana
Female name| Cindy
```

***Wanted result:***

**Table1**:

```
Field1     |Field2
------------------
Male name  | Alex
Female name| Cindy
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good time to use the [Top N predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx).

```
Select Top 1 Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2
From Table1
Left Join Table2 
  on Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1
Order by Table1.Field1, Table2.Field2 ASC
```

By using the Order By, you can sort your data alphabetically, and then use Top N to just take the first record.

Comment: Thank you very much Johnny. I've attempted using your suggested code but it appears that only Female name top 1 result was returned (Male name results did not appear). Would you have any explanation as to why it might be case? Thanks!